# How to unzip python eggs?

Tags: python, py2exe, easy-install, egg

I'm trying to bundle some egg dependencies when using py2exe and as stated on the py2exe site, it doesn't work with those and I need to unzip them first. I've tried to first run `easy_install -m lxml` and then `easy_install --always-unzip lxml==2.2.2`, but it didn't work. Then I tried to set the unzipping behaviour to default by putting it to `distutils.cfg`. I didn't find the latter file, so I've made the `HOME` environment variable and created a `pydistutils.cfg` file there with this content:

```
[easy_install]
zip_ok = 0
```

but easy_install still doesn't unpack the eggs. What is the easiest way to get things done?

Comment: There's no reason the unzip option shouldn't work, unless you just mistyped it.  Try with `-Z` version of that option instead... and are you sure it didn't actually unzip properly?  Check easy-install.pth to see what entry is actually there.  The lxml egg file is marked as "not-zip-safe" so it cannot be installed as an egg anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick hack/workaround: egg files are just zip files, so you can use the python zipfile module to unzip them. Maybe you could rename the easy_install file to "easy_install_pre.exe", and create a new .bat file named "easy_install.bat":

```
easy_install_pre.exe %1
unzip_eggs.py %1
```

Comment: Are you sure they will still work correctly after such manipulations?

Comment: I've unzipped eggs before and used them without problems for the purpose of py2exe. In those cases, I renamed the unzipped file to the package name, and dropped it into my source directory. That said, I use distribute now, and get my egg files unzipped into .egg directories by default.

Answer (score 0):

The zippped package file should be **first removed before reinstalling**. Then is is easy.

All methods of unzipped installation described in the question should work if the zipped package is removed first but does not work without it. Reinstallation of zipped package after unzipped installation is on the contrary possible by normal upgrade without need to remove anything. This was typical for some old easy_install versions related appoximately to period of Python 2.5.